# Camera tracking rendering problems

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, tracking, render-layers

I dont know how to explain it but the camera tracking is not rendering correctly on the blender file i attached... It rendering the markers i used and the hole in the wall and it doesnt look right.. heres a link to the blend and blend1 file:https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwmMw7JLbSKcUjJWMUcwR0U2QlE&usp=sharing

Comment: Could you post some sceenshots? Unfortunaly the .blend file isn't much help because you can't pack the video file...

Comment: Oh ok I can see what I can do